# Negative look ahead not working as expected

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a bizarre situation where *positive lookahead* works as expected but *negative lookahead* doesn't. Please take a look at the following code:

```
<?php

$tweet = "RT @Startup_Collab: @RiseOfRest is headed to OMA & LNK to #showcase our emerging #startup ecosystem. Learn more! https://example.net #Riseof…";

$patterns=array(
    '/#\w+(?=…$)/',
);

$tweet = preg_replace_callback($patterns,function($m)
{
    switch($m[0][0])
    {
        case "#":
            return strtoupper($m[0]);
        break;
    }
},$tweet);


echo $tweet;
```

I want to match any hashtag not followed by `…$` and upper case it (in reality it will be parsed out with an `href` but for simplicity's sake just upper case it for now ).

These are regexes with their corresponding outputs:

`'/#\w+(?=…$)/'` Match any hashtag ending with `…$` and upper-case it, works as expected:

```
RT @Startup_Collab: @RiseOfRest is headed to OMA & LNK to #showcase our emerging #startup ecosystem. Learn more! https://example.net #RISEOF…
```

`'/#\w+(?!…$)/'` Match any hashtag NOT ending with `…$` and upper-case it, does not work, all hashtags are uppercased:

```
RT @Startup_Collab: @RiseOfRest is headed to OMA & LNK to #SHOWCASE our emerging #STARTUP ecosystem. Learn more! https://example.net #RISEOf…
```

Thank  you ver much for any help, suggestions, ideas and patience.

-- Angel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of backtracking that matches the part of a hashtag. Use a possessive quantifier to avoid backtracking into the `\w+` subpattern:

```
/#\w++(?!…$)/
    ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO0gT8/1)

Now, 1 or more word chars are matched, and the `(?!…$)` negative lookahead is only executed once after these word chars matched. If there is a *false* result, no backtracking occurs, and the whole match is failed.

See more on [**possessive quantifiers**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) here.